# AWS SSH Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to connect to my AWS EC2 instance from my Linux machine but I am having trouble doing so. I tried it at home before and it worked so I'm confused as to why it is not working now that I am at school.

I ram `chmod 400 "Key 1.pem"` first.

Then I typed `ssh -i "Key 1.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -vvv`

And here is the output:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [xx.xx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file Key 1.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file Key 1.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version PaloAltoNetworks_0.2
debug1: no match: PaloAltoNetworks_0.2
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/x/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/x/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1070/2048
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:/mAko/GQWYyseCLdwLcgdK5StHC0mLU1aX7LqdtGXWw
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/x/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/x/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/x/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/x/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx.xx.xxx.xxx
debug1: Host 'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/x/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug2: bits set: 1006/2048
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: Key 1.pem ((nil)), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: Key 1.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:0DyNPm5i8KfJCXH+hiFUW0CCnOMLu8uh1PEzjW0OO5w
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I don't know why this isn't working. Could someone please help?

Thanks.

EDIT: I even tried mounting my volume to a different instance but I had exactly the same problem, even when generating a new key.

Comment: Is the key you are using the key that is generated by AWS and added to the server by AWS on server creation, or is this your own key that you added afterwards?

Comment: @WarrenG Generated by AWS and automatically downloaded.

Comment: Oh - the IP address of your instance changes (unless you have configured a static one). Double check that you are using the latest address by copying it from the console again

Comment: @Joe I copied it directly from AWS, it's the right one.

Comment: hmm, perhaps you should clear out your  ~/.ssh/known_hosts file and re-establish the connection again. That has worked for me in the past

Comment: If this is a clean install, and you haven't done anything strange - then there very few reasons why your key would be denied. Are you sure you're using the correct key? Also, and this is a stretch - if you're using linux you should generally avoid spaces in filenames. Try rename the ssh key and remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using user: ubuntu try ec2-user.

E.g: ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com